# extend Generic Method toJSON from jsonlite

Tags: r, build, package, jsonlite

I'm writting a package and I want to extend the generic method `toJSON` included in the `jsonlite` package to handle one of my classes.
I thought that I would be able by doing:

1) Add jsonlite to the Depends in the DESCRIPTION file

2) Take care about the Namespace by adding roxygen tags as

```
#' @importMethodsFrom jsonlite toJSON
#' @export
setMethod("toJSON", signature = "myClass", definition = function(x,...){
    jsonlite::toJSON(as.character(x))
})
```

But when I try to build the package I get the following Error:

> Fehler in setGeneric(f, where = where) :    must supply a function
>   skeleton for 'toJSON', explicitly or via an existing function

In my understanding the roxygen `@importMethodsFrom jsonlite toJSON` tag should exactly do that, provide the generic...

Comment: Thanks for correcting my Tipos, but any Idea on the Topic? :)

Comment: not directly answering your question, but does `jsonify::to_json( x )` work on your class?